# how can i restore files from a filestore folder?

Tags: derby, artifactory

my derby database meet some problem and lost the data. 
now i just have the filestore folder and no have backup file.
so how can i restore files form filestore folder?

the derby database was lost data when I restart my artifactory6.1 which install by docker.
after restart the database's data become the default status when first setup artifactory. and all the repositories's data were not find.
I were use some tool to see the database it only have a little data,and dump to file is only 2MB.
but the derby's dat file is still have 200MB size so maybe can restore the database? but i don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

As Artifactory utilizes a checksum based storage, the files in the filestore are saved by checksum and not names, and the names of the files are saved in the DataBase. This means you can not know which file is which in the filestore.
In order to better understand your scenario can you please provide some information:

- Are you using an external Derby DataBase or the built-in one that comes with Artifactory?
- In the derby's 'dat' folder do you have multiple files or just one?
- Please share with us the 'db.properties' file located in *$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc*

In addition, there is a way you can connect the new Derby Database and point it to the Derby data folder (located in *$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/data/derby*).
Simply bring up the IJ tool, and type

```
connect 'jdbc:derby:/full/path/to/the/database/folder';
```

If you don't know how to run 'ij', look in the Derby documentation for the Derby tutorial, and work through it; Then go back to trying to open your DataBase.

After connecting the Derby DataBase to the Derby data folder, you can bring up Artifactory and see if the data is restored.

Please also note that JFrog always recommends to backup the DataBase and the filestore in order to avoid scenarios like this.

We hope this helps.